# How do I know if my Django project is ready to be deployed?

Tags: django, web, deployment, hosting

I already finished my project that I made with django, and I want to upload it. I already bought the domain, and they are about to host it for me.. once they give me the host, I just upload it and that's it? Or are there more steps to do within the code? What do I have to do?. that is, once everything is uploaded to the host, will everything be seen?
And the Admin will continue to work, when in the search engine put /admin/ ???.
that is, I wonder what are all the steps to follow so that once I host my page everything can be seen.
that is, what things would have to be configured in the congif.py, and other things.
I would appreciate a lot if you give me advice/tips/solutions..

What I know is that I have to change the debug to DEBUG=False ...
And I don't know anything else, once they pass me the port and other host information, I simply upload the files of my project to the host and that's it, nothing more? Isn't it necessary to write more code to show it?

Excuse me, I have never displayed a page

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of steps involved in deploying your code to production. I suggest you check out a guide like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) to get a better idea of what you need to do in order to deploy your website. Additionally, you can run the command `python manage.py check --deploy` for a quick, though insufficient, review of your code to see if it is ready to be pushed to production.

Answer (score 0):

Django is an excellent choice for developing basic to more advanced websites. The web framework works well in local and production environments. Just the same way the local environment server is not suitable for a production environment, there are things you need to configure before deploying your Django website. Take a look at the links below

Https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/

https://github.com/vintasoftware/django-production-launch-checklist/blob/master/checklist-en.md

Comment: bro can you help me? I already have the domain, the host, and when I upload the files of my django project in FileZilla, when I enter the page in google, I only see the directories that are inside the "public html" folder, that is, I can access the folders and files of my project from the page, but I want the templates and others to be seen. as I do? It's a serious project, I'm 16 years old and I made a page about a job I have, and I don't know how to make it look. Could you help me? I'm from Argentina, I could pay you if you ask me, but I need help bro

Comment: I already started to follow you on twitter, and I'll tell you, I made my page with django, calling many static load functions, either for template inheritance, that is, for the footer and nabvar, and to load images/urls, and the rest..
Now, I already bought a domain, and they hosted that domain for me in a company.
How do I make the templates appear on the page? to run the static load, for the css and other things. I do not know how to do it

Comment: All the tutorials I see are with other companies that upload the page. I want my django project to appear on the host that I buy.

Comment: www.familiacan.com.ar is my host with my domain.